# Creating a Slider Like This?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not sure what this is called so I can't search for it, but if you goto http://vps.net/product/cloud-servers/ and scroll down to VPS nodes, how is this created? and is there any tutorial or anything I can take a look at? What kind of slider is this?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery UI's slider has that basic functionality: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the jquery ui slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: so I could create the exact same slider with this? I noticed it changes multiple fields at once and I haven't seen that example with the slider you linked, just want to make sure it will work

Comment: Yes. Obviously they've done some work to customise it, but if you look at the source code, that's what they're using.

Answer (score 3):

They are using a jQuery-UI slider, with a customized callback that highlights the little node boxes:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 1,
    max: 15,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        // Un-highlight nodes
        $('.node').removeClass('highlight');
        // Highlight all nodes up to value selected
        $('.node:lt('+ui.value+')').addClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

This is my example code, I didn't want to parse through their obfuscated code to see what they were actually doing for their callback.  It is probably very similar to this.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/A8ccw/1/

You can get rid of the step behavior if you change the `step` value to a fractional value, like `.01`, and then using `Math.floor()` to determine your highlight index.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/A8ccw/4/

Here is a demo that updates multiple data fields:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/A8ccw/8/

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/